# Does Flash Builder 4.6 create LZMA compressed SWFs?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

Does Flash Builder 4.6 create LZMA compressed SWFs and also are the RSL framework LZMA compressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Falcon may add support for this. There are supposed to be programs out there that can compress the file after the fact. Though I don't know what those are.

Answer (score 1):

The entire SWF file is not compressed, though elements within the file - images, ActionScript bytecode, sounds etc - are individually compressed in blocks (I believe zlib is used). This is important for the flash player to be able to decompress parts of the swf as it loads, in order to get it playing quickly.

Usually you won't get a lot of extra compression by compressing the entire SWF file, since most of the data inside is already compressed.

Comment: Is this happening with the FB 4.6 compiler or Falcon?

Comment: This is in every version of Flash and Flex for a good number of years - since Flash Player 6, which predates Flex.